# How is OData and JMESPath related?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata, jmespath

I have come across JMESPath and would like to use JMESPath instead of OData (is it actually replaceable?) on asp.net webapi. Can someone shed some light on me please.

Thanks in advance

Pavan

Answer (score 1):

Odata is a layer on top of your database (mostly used in .net ) and it is similar to IQueryable ( eg. lambdas)

According to me it looks kinda similar, except that odata has a builtin $count=true function ( odata v4).

JMESPath is not available for .Net though, so i wouldn't use it on aspnet webapi

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am mistaking but it looks like JMESPath is to JSON as XPath is to XML...